# Unity: Последовательность выполнения функции Start

Tags: unity3d

Чтобы объяснить суть вопроса я сделал такой мини эксперимент.
У меня есть 2 скрипта - FirstScript.cs, SecondScript.cs

Это первый скрипт

```
public class FirstScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int testNumber = 0;

    void Start()
    {
        testNumber = 1;
        Debug.Log(testNumber.ToString() + " - by First Script");
    }
}
```

А это второй

```
public class SecondScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public FirstScript firstScript;

    void Start()
    {
        firstScript.testNumber = 2;
        Debug.Log(firstScript.testNumber.ToString() + " - by Second Script");
    }
}
```

Как видно я пытался через второй скрипт в старте изменить значение первого.
И в Console я получил вот это -

[image]

Вы видите что в конце выполняется Start того скрипта в котором находится переменная.
Теперь мой вопрос: **Как-то можно изменить этот последовательность?**

Comment: Project Settings - Script Execution Order

Comment: @trollingchar спасибо! Если хотите можете делать это ответом.

Comment: В целом, не рекомендовал бы такую эквилибристику. Лучше всего следовать банальнейшему правилу - в Awake класс инициализирует себя. В Start - взаимодействует с другими. Это решает множество проблем.

Comment: @M.Green если будут проблемы со скриптами буду пользоваться вашим советом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Порядок выполнения скриптов можно задать в меню **Edit - Project Settings - Script Execution Order**. Скрипты будут выполняться сверху вниз. Не указанные явно скрипты выполнятся в блоке **Default**.

[Документация](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MonoManager.html)